# Difference between "make your way home" and "go home"

Tags: differences

Could somebody explain to me the difference between "make your way home" and "go home" . Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: To the extent that there *is* any meaningful "difference", it's much the same as the difference between *I'm going to the little boys' room* and *I'm going to the toilet* (or *washroom* or whatever, for Americans). The circumlocutory form may be facetious or euphemistic, for example. If rendered as ***wend** your way home* it may even be a device for showing off the speaker's command of (dated/archaic) English. You'd probably need to know the *exact* context to have any hope of understanding why a speaker might choose one form over another.

Comment: The second is the unmarked expression; the first at least hints at something interesting or demanding in the necessary journey.

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said.  From a literary standpoint, "make your way home" infers something that will make the journey challenging/demanding or interesting and has an expectation of something newsworthy to the reader.  "Go home" has none of those expectations.

Comment: Yeah, "make your way" implies that some effort may be required, possibly because of distance, possibly because of weather, possibly because of your state of drunkenness.

Comment: One phrase is longer than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Both "making your way home" and "going home" mean to leave where you are and proceed to your place of residence.  The former, however, is employed to describe an arduous journey. From *Hope: A Memoir* by Bernard Warach:

> I rose at five, washed, had a cup of coffee, and walked to the
>   Independent subway station at First Avenue and Houston Street.  I took
>   the D train express to 125th Street and changed to the local to 135th
>   Street.  I had a very long climb up several hundred steps from the
>   base of St. Nicholas Part to St. Nicholas Terrace above and a further
>   walk to the college buildings, and my class was at eight.   There were
>   frequent snows and ice during the winter on the park steps and
>   terrace.   I carried a heavy school bag with textbooks....  I then
>   reversed direction to **make my way home.**

Go [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.8142137,-73.9496042,3a,75y,327.35h,90.49t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s0jbBdex-mfEMCWvlsEMUpg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) for a view of the steps from Nicholas Avenue to Nicholas Terrace above.

The obstacles are not required.  It's acceptable to say, "I left the party and made my way home without incident or hindrance."

Answer (score 1):

*Make your way* means to set off on a journey. It's not clear whether you will arrive at the destination, or even whether that will remain your destination. All that's known is your intention to **head** in that direction, i.e., with that as your initial destination.

*Go home* is more ambiguous and, without more context, more definitive: a priori, you **will** go home, and will thus get (arrive) there.

*Make your way* is about the journey, as a process (maybe even an adventure). *Go* is about the destination.

When you *make your way home* you might end up stopping here or there, changing your route (detours), etc. What will happen on that journey is perhaps unknown, but it is what will be of interest in the text the follows. When you *go home*, all that matters, a priori, is that you left the current location and you will end up at home.